# Drupal 7 pagination in custom view

Tags: drupal, pagination, drupal-7, drupal-views

I've created a custom view for a page called views-view--projects-landing-page.tpl.php and I want to include pagination within the page.

I'm currently displaying all content within the page but would like to paginate this to 8 items.

Please can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the help you pointed me in the right direction by chaning the view however due to my custom template I needed to add

```
<?php print $pager; ?>
```

to get it to display in the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On the edit page for the view, make sure you're on the Page display tab. Then look under the *Basic settings* subsection and look for the **Use pager** option.

Comment: The problem is I'm using a custom template and can't seem to get the pagination in the template. If i remove the template I get the pagination but lose design elements I have.